Calculating water velocity with multiple pipe sizes
When calculating water flow rate from observed gallons per minute and pipe size, do you always use the smallest pipe size in the run? In my house, for example, the incoming main is 1"; it is immediately reduced to 5/8" for the water meter, and from there reduced to 1/2" from a pressure regulator.
The runs of 5/8" and 1/2" pipe here are all quite small - less than 6".
So when entering the numbers into a flow rate calculator, should I use the 1/2" pipe size, the 1" main size, or something in between?

The volume of water moving through the sequence of pipes is the same in every pipe. The velocity of the water (and the pressure loss per unit length) will be different in each section of pipe, proportional to the size of the section. To calculate velocity in a certain section  you'd use the actual size of that section. But it seems like maybe there's a bigger-picture question/issue that hasn't floated to the surface yet..?

@GregHill, thanks - the bigger problem is apparently that I need to read more, because this question doesn't make much sense given that knowledge. I was trying to calculate the size the pipes in the house need to be to maintain the same flow rate. The quick answer, I think, is "the inner diameter should not be any smaller than the smallest incoming pipe."

One way to approach engineered pipe sizing is to first choose the design velocity. One can then calculate eg "I need to feed a shower head at 1.5 GPM while maintaining velocity in the pipe below 4 ft/sec. What is the minimum pipe diameter required? And then, with a given pressure PSI at the supply and knowing the distance from the supply to the shower head, what will be the pressure loss in that minimum-size pipe? Should I pick a larger pipe so as to incur less pressure loss, which will also reduce velocity further?"
